# VScode debugger can't find source maps

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Hi so over the last couple days I've been trying to get the VScode debugger to detect the source maps for my type script code base.

When I set a break point in the type script it turns grey and the tooltip says `"Breakpoint ignored because generated code not found"`

I've inculded my launch.json file

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible Node.js debug attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/src/server.ts",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceRoot}/dist/**/*.js"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Gulp develop",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceRoot}/dist/**/*.js"
            ],
            "args": [
                "develop"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach",
            "port": 9229,
            "protocol": "inspector",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceRoot}/dist/**/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And my gulp file

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var typescript = require('gulp-typescript');
var notify = require('gulp-notify');
var changed = require('gulp-changed');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var del = require('del');
var vinylPaths = require('vinyl-paths');
var nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon');
var debug = require('gulp-debug');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
var compiler = compiler || null;

var paths = {
    ts: 'src/**/*.ts',
    dist: 'dist/'
}

gulp.task('develop', function (callback) {
    runSequence('clean', 'build', function () {
         nodemon({
            exec: 'node --inspect',
            script: 'dist/server.js', 
            watch: 'src',
            ext: 'ts',
            tasks: ['build']
        });
        callback();
    });
});

gulp.task('build', function () {
    if (!compiler) {
        compiler = typescript.createProject('tsconfig.json', { "typescript": require('typescript') });
    }
    return gulp.src(paths.ts)
        .pipe(changed(paths.dist, { extension: '.js' }))
        .pipe(debug())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
        .pipe(compiler())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.', { includeContent: false, sourceRoot: '/src' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist));
});

gulp.task('clean', function() {
    return gulp.src([paths.dist])
        .pipe(vinylPaths(del));
});
```

And Here's some example directory structure

```
dist/server.d.ts  
dist/server.js 
dist/server.js.map
src/server.ts
gulpfile.js
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.